# MVC reload page after Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My delete method is working but you have to manually refresh the browser to see that it has been deleted.  I simply want to reload the page but I can't get it to work.  Can someone tell me the proper way to do this?

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    var recipientOrchestrator = new RecipientsOrchestrator();
    RecipientsViewModel model = recipientOrchestrator.GetRecipientsPageData();
    return View(model);
}


[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Delete(int id, int applicationId) 
{
    var recipientOrchestrator = new RecipientsOrchestrator();
    recipientOrchestrator.DeleteRecipient(id, applicationId);

    return Index();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```